# #python extract info from a list

Tags: python, list

not an expert in Python... I'd like to extract infos from a list.
Here is the list:
[image]

and here is my code:

```
    for item in data ["items"]:
        for p in item ["standings"]["clan"]["participants"]:
                print("%s %s" % (
                    p["tag"],
                    p["name"],
))
```

with this error:

```
  File "_players_.py", line 26, in <module>
    for p in item ["standings"]["clan"]["participants"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help please ?

Another bigger view of the pic:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: It looks like `item ["standings"]` is a list. You need to iterate over this list.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your picture, `item["standings"]` yields a list, not a dictionary. That would be confirmed by the error which details that a list is indexed using a string. So, I assume you would want something along the lines of:

```
...
for s in item["standings"]:
    for p in s["clan"]["participants"]:
        ...
```

Comment: here is a bigger picture and it's a dictionary

Comment: `items[0]` is a dict holding the key `"standings"`. `items[0]["standings"]` is a list, containing a bunch of further dicts, such as `items[0]["standings"][0]` which holds the key `"clan"`

Comment: Your second picture clearly shows `items[0]["standings"]` is a list of size 5.

Comment: i'd like all of the content for "participants" but not only for [0] but all of them

Comment: Take a look at the code snipped in my answer, you can loop through your participants as you used to, with the only difference that there are multiple standings instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a .json file you can try this:

```
print(json_file['items'][0]['standings'][0]['clan']['participants'][number of your information])
```

hope this is helpful :-)

Comment: i saved it as a json file for a better view but it is a response from a website API.

Comment: to get the "data", I have this just before the code:  data = json.loads(response)